# How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have developed Rest API using Node JS, Express and MongoDb.
I have istalled MongoDB into one machine with Ubuntu Server OS and Node JS App on machine with Ubuntu Server OS.
Now i need to deploy to Production enviroments with a reverse proxy.
I have seen this post as example:
[Deploy Node JS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Now my question is: the reverse proxy server using Nginx must be deploy on a separete machine? Instead Nginx is possible to use Apache?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy nginx on same machine.So your setup will be nginx listening to 80 port of the machine for incoming requests and redirecting all requests to you application as per you have specified in nginx configuration.
if you are deploying nginx on same machine and having application 8080. you can do some thing like this.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

and if you can configure apache to redirect request to your application you can replace nginx with apache.(but i have not worked with apache so as per me above configurations works.but if you want some help you can read this one [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension))